# Jenkins declarative pipeline with acitve choice parametres

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a question (but based on my knowledge and research I am not etirely sure if it is even possbile), I have jenkinsfile (due to IP I cannot provide production code so only example):

```
@Library('my-jenkins-library') _
List myList = ['\"AAA\"', '\"BBB\"', '\"CCC\"']
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            // description: ,
            filterLength: 1,
            filterable: false,
            name: 'MYLIST',
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631394568814439613978',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script:
                        'return[\'Not applicable\']'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script:
                        "return $myList"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        string(name: "VERSIONS", defaultValue: "nothing to see")
    ])
])

pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('my init') {
            steps {
                echo "${params}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This pipeline is in our release cycle limitted only to one version (in parameter VERSIONS), outside of release cycle there are enough resources to run this pipeline multiple times in parallel with different version. For this second pipeline that is triggered only manually was created that it will split the VERSIONS and executes first pipeline multiple times in parallel based of number of versions. Lets say that: VERSIONS=1 2 3, than first pipeline is executed thrice with different version.

Actual problem: second pipeline must have exactly same parameters as the first one in order to make this work.
Question 1: is there any possible way to load parameters from different file? I was able to  only find some solutions with standard parameters, but none of them was working with Active Choice Parameters.
Question 2: Due to fact that I did not write the second pipeline and I do not understand how it works (unfortunatelly) I cannot porvide even example of that but I would like to ask if there is some way (outside the magic my colleague did) to achive that for example in the first pipeline. Something like (pseudo-code):

```
@Library('my-jenkins-library') _
List myList = ['\"AAA\"', '\"BBB\"', '\"CCC\"']
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            // description: ,
            filterLength: 1,
            filterable: false,
            name: 'MYLIST',
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631394568814439613978',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script:
                        'return[\'Not applicable\']'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script:
                        "return $myList"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        string(name: "VERSIONS", defaultValue: "nothing to see")
    ])
])

pipeline {
    stages {
        agent {
            label 'any'
        }
        // pseudo code bellow
        VERSIONS_LIST = split(VERSIONs, delimiter - " ")
        VERSIONS_LIST.each { VERSIONS ->
        parallel {
            stage('my init') {
                steps {
                    echo "${params}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Due to fact that Active Choice Plugins have very specific rules (especially the referenced ones) I was stuck with them. I tried using File Parameter plugin but it is not feasible because it still requires user interaction and cannot be automated, I have tried ChatGPT but he seems to have very huge issues understanding the difference between parametres and properties (solutions provided by the AI worked only for properties and even those requires some modififications). I searched forums but they provided only partial solutions for properties (again).

Comment: Do I understand correctly if I say you need to launch the second pipeline after the first one with the exact same paramters?